# MuleSoft 4 http request

Tags: mulesoft

I am new to MuleSoft
when i am giving output expression like below i am getting an data sense error, can you please help

```
#[output application/json --- {errorType:error.errorType, error:error.description}]
```

> Description Resource Path Location Type Scripting language error on
>   expression '#[output application/json --- {errorType:error.errorType,
>   error:error.descrip...'. Reason: Invalid input '#', expected using,
>   if, ???, unless or not (line 1, column 1): . validations.xml
>   /validations/src/main/mule Listener Message Flow Error

Comment: Can you post more of the config where the error is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know without a snippet from the configuration XML exactly what your issue is, but one problem I see is that your dataweave does not start with a 
"%dw 2.0" In mule 4 there are two languages. Mule Expression language, which is default in most components (ie #[vars.name] is MEL), and dataweave 2.0 which is default in Transform Message components.  You can however, as you've attempted to do, use dataweave inside of Mule Expressions.  You have it mostly right, but it must start with "%dw 2.0" at the beginning.  So it should look like this.

```
#[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- {errorType:error.errorType, error:error.description}]
```

However, judging by the error message, it looks like you're attempting to use MEL in a place where it is not allowed. If you provide a snippet of the configuration XML for this component, I can be more helpful.

Comment: In mule 4 there is no MEL, only dataweave 2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [MEL](https://learnmule.wordpress.com/2015/09/07/mule-expression-language-mel/) in Mule 4. It is migrated to DW2.0. Please refer link https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/migration-mel